# Bayesian update of normal distribution given noisy binary search response

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

How do we go about calculating a posterior with a prior given N data points of the form `greater than X` or `less than Y`, when those data points are noisy (that is, `greater than X` can be incorrect)?

Example:

We start with the posterior normal distribution of variable X with mean 1 and variance 1. We do series of tests with the following results:

```
test x=1: less than X
test x=2: less than X
test x=5: greater than X
test x=6: less than X
test x=4: greater than X
test x=10: greater than X
test x=12: greater than X
```

Given such results, I'd think that that mean of X variable is not `1` - probably something around `5`. But how can I derive this mean and variance?

Comment: The probabilistic bisection algorithm is closely related to your question. See e.g. Waeber, R. (2013). *Probabilistic bisection search for stochastic root-finding* (PhD thesis). Cornell University. Retrieved from http://people.orie.cornell.edu/shane/theses/ThesisRolfWaeber.pdf

Comment: @Kodiologist - Yes, that's relevant. But it seems that this method confines the variable to some pre-defined range ([0,1] in the example can be scaled - but it is still some arbitrary scale).

Comment: @Kodiologist - and not only it is scaled, the probability function appears to be discrete, while I am interested in obtaining real-valued unbounded estimate.

Comment: The posterior distribution p(X|data) is proportion to the prior p(X) times the likelihood p(data|X). You must specify the likelihood. And if the likelihood involves unknowns other than X, you much specify priors for those unknowns as well.

Comment: @mef - Prior p(X) can be taken as `N~(0,1)`, and p(data|X) is for a case of one data point simply `norm cdf(data_point, X)` (can be easily extended to multiple data points).

Comment: Let p(data|X) = p(y1|X) x p(y2|X) x ... x p(yn|X), where p(yi|X) is a *density* that integrates to 1 holding X fixed. I don't know what norm-cdf(yi, X) means in this context. (At a minimum you need a mean and a variance to specify a normal distribution.) You should be able to answer the following question: How would you generate observations if you know X?

Comment: @mef Yes, my answer is wrong, I see it now. `p(data|X)` here measures the actual noise (without noise it would be exactly 0 or 1). In my current attempt, I used the approach from the paper linked above - I take \beta (0 < \beta < 1/2) as "boost power", and use `p(data|X) = \beta` if `data` is on the "wrong" side and `p(data|X) = 1 - \beta` if `data` is on the "right" side (with probability renormalization to 1 after that). The resulting distribution does not look like normal - but I'm currently taking mean and variance of this skewed distribution and replace it with new normal distribution.